# Is there any way to get data from @DataProvider annotation in Selenium Cucumber testng framework?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, testng, bdd, testng-dataprovider

I am working on a selenium-TestNg project where we are integrating cucumber framework, I need to get the data through @DataProvider technique.

Comment: Did u tried Data Tables cucumber feature file provide ?

Comment: Yes Data Table works, but the thing is I am looking for a way to integrate existing testNg framwork with cucumber.

Comment: Where you able to succeed in integrating testng data provider with cucumber @testergirl

Answer (score 1):

Well you can achieve by using [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) or [qaf-bdd](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario.html#data-driven-scenario). You can use inbuilt data provider available for csv/xml/json/excel/database or create your custom TestNg data-provider and use it. Here is the [BDD-Example](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf/blob/master/test/resources/scenarios/scenarioWithCustomDataProvider.bdd) that uses data-provider with different arguments. Refer below example:

```
SCENARIO: Custom Data provider Example 
META-DATA: {"dataProvider":"my-custom-dp", "dataProviderClass":"my.project.impl.CustomDataProvider","description":"Data driven test that uses custom data provider"}
    Given I am on fruits and colors activity
    When i select '${fruit}'
    Then the color should be '${color}'

END
```

Data-provider implementation:

```
package my.project.impl;

import java.util.Map;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.collections.Maps;

/**
 * @author chirag.jayswal
 *
 */
public class CustomDataProvider {

    @DataProvider(name="my-custom-dp")
    public static Object[][] dataProviderForBDD(){

        Map<Object, Object> rec1 = Maps.newHashMap();
        m.put("fruit", "grapes");
        m.put("color", "green");

        Map<Object, Object> rec2 = Maps.newHashMap();
        m.put("fruit", "banana");
        m.put("color", "yellow");

        return new Object[][]{ {rec1},{rec2}};
    }
}
```